# Exclude domain from redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have multiple domains handled by an Apache server and I would like all of them to be redirected to HTTPS, except for one (called www.example.com below). What I have so far is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS, unfortunately *including* http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com – so clearly the second RewriteCond is not working as it should. What am I missing?

Comment: Your rule seems fine...

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? What 3xx status do you see on the redirect? As Dusan points out, the RewriteCond directive itself is OK. So my guess is you are either seeing a cached response or _something else_ is triggering the redirect you are seeing?

Comment: You could setup 2 VirtualHosts.  One for www.example.com:80 which does not redirect, the other for the other :80 domains which does.  This avoids any redirection.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, there are other directives in the .htaccess. But even if I remove everything else, and do ```curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -I http://www.example.com?foo``` to keep the server from using the cache, I get a 302 redirect to ```https://www.example.com?foo```.

Comment: Although that would seem to be impossible given just the directives above. Try _adding_ something to the redirected URL. For example: `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?bar [QSA,R,L]` and request `http://www.example.com/?foo` as you did before. (You were missing a slash before, CURL "fixes" the request URL. You most probably _need_ the `L` flag, unless this is the very last directive in the file. You should always be explicit and include the `R` flag, even though an _external redirect_ is implied by the _substitution_ in this instance.)